# Laravel route acts craizy

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

Hy i have this http://laravel.io/bin/jaPB

The problem is when i go to:
domain.com      -> it serves the homepage (**wich is ok**)
domain.com/foo  -> it serves a subpage (**still ok**)

but when i go from one of those to:
domain.com/en   -> it gives an error (**not ok**)

But after hitting refresh its ok.

So again when i'm on domain.com/en first time error after refresh ok
Same goes to subpage like domain.com/en/contact first time error after refresh ok

I would point out that the error says first time it tries to go to PublicPageController@subpage 
but this shouldn't happen when i go to domain.com/en it should need to go to PublicPageController@homepage

Any idea ?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess here form looking at the way you set up the locale-based routes is that the `Session::get('urilang)` isn't set the first time you visit, hence the error, and is only set once you've been to a page first.

Now, I haven't yet had to deal with multilingual sites, but as far as I'm aware the way you're doing it is not the correct way. Instead think of the lang key as a URI parameter, and use the filter to validate and set it for the routes. Something a bit like the below code:

```
// Main and subpage - not default language
Route::group(array('prefix' => '{lang}', 'before' => 'detectLanguage'), function () {
    Route::get('', 'PublicPage@homepage');
    Route::get('{slug}', 'PublicPage@subpage');
});

// Main and subpage - default language
Route::group(array('before' => 'setDefaultLanguage'), function () {
    Route::get('/', 'PublicPage@homepage');
    Route::get('/{slug}', 'PublicPage@subpage');
});

Route::filter('detectLanguage', function($route, $request, $response, $value){
    // hopefully we could do something here with our named route parameter "lang" - not really on sure the details though

    // set default 
    $locale = 'hu'; 
    $lang = '';

    // The 'en' -> would come from db and if there is more i would of corse use in array
    if (Request::segment(1) == 'en') 
    {
        $lang = 'en';
        $locale = 'en';
    }

    App::setLocale($locale);
    Session::put('uriLang', $lang);
    Session::put('locale', $locale); 
});


Route::filter('setDefaultLanguage', function($route, $request, $response, $value){
    App::setLocale('hu');
    Session::put('uriLang', '');
    Session::put('locale', 'hu'); 
});
```

I don't know if you can use a segment variable in a `Route::group` prefix, but you should certainly have a go at it as it'd be the most useful.

That said, I wouldn't advise setting up default language routes that mimic specific language routes but without the language segment. If I were you, I'd set up a special root route that will redirect to `/{defaultlang}/` just so you have fewer routing issues.

Comment: Thank's for your help, your code looks prity cool, i have only one problem though. Everything works except domain.com/en/foo Because there the PublicPageController thinks the slug is "en". Any idea? Ohh and i'm gonna edit the code a bit because there are some typos

Comment: Solved it, but it's really not that clean, and i agree with you on everything, thanks for your help man, really saved my day.

Comment: Cheers for the edits, I think I kinda rushed that one out, sorry. Good question on the route conflict thing. If I'm honest I'm not sure of the exact way around this (though as I understand it, routes registered after another route that would match the same URI will override it, so you could look into reversing the order here, but I think that'd just create problems the other way around for you). So yeah, this is pretty much why I suggest (at the end of the answer) not having the dual routing system - get one system and stick with it, because it makes things less crazy.

Comment: Ahh cool, no problem. Glad to have helped you get to your own solution :)